# Cover updatepanel while updateprogress

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

How?  I have cascading dropdowns, I want them to be un-clickable while the panel is updating (or at least appear to be).

Preferably using jQuery, [Hide UpdatePanel during UpdateProgress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509266/hide-updatepanel-during-updateprogress) was how I was thinking it would work but I don't know how to begin the function.

```
$("#imgID").closest('div').hide()  ?
```

**Edit:**  Even better would be if instead of hiding the dropdowns, they are just covered in semi-transparent grey while the gif does its thing over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use UpdateProgress and link it to your Update Panel, everytime a Ajax postback is detected the UpdateProgress is shown, with CSS you could overlay this over all or some elemets on the page and set the opacity so its slightly see through.

Comment: adding the following to in <ProgressTemplate> works, but the div is only as big as the image:
    <div id="UPdiv" style="position:absolute; z-index:1; left:50%;
                                            top:50%; background-color:Gray; opacity:0.5; height:500 px;">

any ideas on how to expand the size since setting 'height' doesn't seem to have any effect?

Comment: spaces between numbers and "px" are cursed things  got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i use [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) it's call BlockUI it's use JQuery and very easy to use.
you can catch an Update on `UpdatePanel` and use it.

Have a nice programming.