# asp.net updatepanel blocking clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an asp.net 4.0 web forms application that I'm working on and I'm trying to modify the behavior of an updatepanel.

The current behavior is that while the update panel loads, I can click on links but they don't work until the panel is finished loading. Because the panel takes a long time to load, users are blocked from navigating the page and I need to figure out a way to fix that.

Does anyone have a good idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better suggestion is to use triggers as described here: [How can I defer loading UpdatePanel content until after the page renders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877951/how-can-i-defer-loading-updatepanel-content-until-after-the-page-renders?lq=1)

There could be another way where you hide the panel while the update in progress as described here: [Hide UpdatePanel during UpdateProgress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509266/hide-updatepanel-during-updateprogress?rq=1)

May I also suggest you to study [Understanding ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) because this will help you to create a better solution fit for your project.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they're definitely the right direction. I'm still trying to understand the way ASP.NET works, so maybe you can help me out this this: when I add the <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="hiddenAsyncTrigger" EventName="Click" /> under <triggers> and put the following javascript code in, __doPostBack('<%= hiddenAsyncTrigger.ClientID %>', ''); the UpdatePanel no longer finishes loading/updating. Any idea on why that is?